# 3D pdf adobe api for javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe

I know that Adobe 3D pdf support JavaScript. So, I have JavaScript code in Three.js for 3D models in 3D world.

Is it possible to have same (or similar) code in 3D pdf?
I mean, I load 3D models, and do things with 3D models and have that all in 3D pdf?

What do I have to have to have this?
Can I create scene with Adobe API?
Is it free, Adobe API?

Answer (score 0):

You can add JavaSCript to a 3D Annotation using Adobe Acrobat manually or just about any PDF library tool that supports Rich Media Annotations or will allow you to access objects at the COS dictionary level. I can advise better if you can tell me what programming languages you are most proficient at. One thing to note is that there is no physics engine or collision detection in the Acrobat JavaScript for 3D API, you'd need to add that yourself... though it is certainly possible.

Comment: Thank You. Language could be Java but could be any other, it's not a problem. What is COS dictionary? Some link, please. Physics and collision are not important at all, it is just presentation level.

Comment: COS is a generic object in PDF that all other objects are built from. It's a reference to the Acrobat bata 1 code name. Both iText and Datalogics PDF Java Toolkit directly support 3D PDF and the associated dictionaries required to ass scripts. You can probably get PDFBox to do it but you'd need to write the underlying code to get at the right objects. However, you'll need a U3D version of your model, you can't define new meshes in Acrobat JavaScript.

Comment: Thank You, I will invastigate iText.